# Using * in grep path called from bash script

Tags: bash, grep, wildcard

I'm trying to write a bash script to search my source directories for a string using `grep` -- and no, I can't use `ack`.

The directory structure is

Headers: .../*product*/package/product-*module*/i/*filename*.h

Source: .../*product*/package/product-*module*/s/*filename*.c

I'd like the option to specify *module* or not (search all modules), which is the point of argument `$2`. Problem is, I can't get either `*$2` or `"*$2"` to work in the script (please see below).

**edit:** The former attempt results in no output whatsoever, and the latter results in "grep: No such file or directory"

How do I correctly use `*` with `grep` if I want to compound it with another string?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: search_src -[si] < module | all > < target >

if [ $1 == "-s" ]; then
   fext="c"
   subdir="s"
elif [ $1 == "-i" ]; then
   fext="h"
   subdir="i"
else
   fext="[ch]"
   subdir="[si]"
fi

if [ $2 == "all" ]; then
   module=*;
else
   module=*$2;
fi

shift 2;

grep \"$@\" ~/workspace/*/package/$module/$subdir/*.$fext
```

Comment: are you looking for somethine like `grep -r *.{c,h}`. `-r` has the option of doing recursive copy !

Comment: No, as I understand `-r` will report matches in all subdirectories, but  the aim of this script is to look at only some of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a safe eval and some minor modifications:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Usage: search_src -[si] < module | all > < target >

if [[ $1 == "-s" ]]; then
   fext="c"
   subdir="s"
elif [[ $1 == "-i" ]]; then
   fext="h"
   subdir="i"
else
   fext="[ch]"
   subdir="[si]"
fi

if [[ $2 == "all" ]]; then
   module='*';
else
   module='*"$2"';
fi

shopt -s nullglob
eval "files=(~/workspace/*/package/$module/$subdir/*.$fext)"

IFS=$' \t\n'
[[ $# -gt 2 && ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]] && grep -e "${*:3}" -- "${files[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one small issue... if I issue `search_sh -s all hello world` this lists all lines containing either "hello" or "world". The original behavior of the script would search for "hello world"

Comment: Thanks! Although... I was able to make it work by just removing the `shift 2;` and modifying the last line to `eval "grep \"${@:3}\" ~/workspace/*/package/$module/$subdir/*.$fext"`. I'm not really sure what `shopt`, `IFS`, and `grep --` do, so is there a significant safety and/or performance advantage to yours? [edit: mind you, I already do some checking of the arguments, but omitted them in this code snippet... sorry for that confusion]

Comment: @EvanW I actually used "${*:3}" as well on a further update. There's no signifant advantage with using -- for grep actually, but sometimes when a filename begins with `-` it is interpreted as an option instead and cause syntax error to grep. It's just a practice. Also, about settings IFS, `"${*:3}"`'s separator depend on it actually so it's just a precaution just in case IFS becomes different externally and becomes applicable to the script through export.